# How does the method .call() work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railscasts

I'm implementing authorization in an app according to [this Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2).

In one of the instance methods, Ryan Bates is using the method .call and I don't understand what exactly it is doing. [This is the code for the whole model](https://github.com/railscasts/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2/blob/master/forum-after/app/models/permission.rb). And this is the particular method:

```
def allow?(controller, action, resource = nil)
  allowed = @allow_all || @allowed_actions[[controller.to_s, action.to_s]]
  allowed && (allowed == true || resource && allowed.call(resource))
end
```

The resource argument is an instance object and the local variable `allowed` is supposed to be a boolean value.

Comment: Apparently, `allowed` can also be a proc. Look at the definition (`@allowed_actions[[controller.to_s, action.to_s]]`).

Comment: `allowed` can also be a *method object* ..Check `p allowed.instance_of?(Method)`...

Comment: I assume that to understand this I need to understand Proc. And to understand Proc I fully have to understand closures. And to understand closures I'd better take a week's break and buy some books. I'm sorry for a bad question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`call` evaluates the proc or method receiver passing its arguments to it.

```
pr = ->a{a.map(&:upcase)}
pr.call(%w[hello world])
# => ["HELLO", "WORLD"]

m = "hello".method(:concat)
m.call(" world")
# => "hello world"
```

It is used to call back a piece of code that has been passed around as an object.